# html css un-expected gap around left side and top need to fix

Tags: html, css

okay so i have started out desingning a website from scratch with html and css

here is a link to what i have so far

https://c9.io/ashg1990/secure/workspace/client/index.html

and here is my code below

html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>ARG Modular</title>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="head">
  <img class="header" src="img/headlogo.png" alt="logo" />

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

and css file

```
    body {
    background-color:#A8A1A3;
    width:110%;
}
div.head {
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
left bottom,
color-stop(0, #FFFFFF),
color-stop(1, #A8A1A3)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #A8A1A3 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #A8A1A3 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #A8A1A3 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #A8A1A3 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #A8A1A3 100%);
width:110%;

}

img.header {

display: block;
margin-right: auto;

}
```

how can i fix it so it does no have the gap around the `<div class="head">`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the body margin to 0.  Should also do the same for padding.

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

You might also want to consider using something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I'd include `padding: 0` as well.

Comment: @downvoter, If you think I have something incorrect, please leave a comment, I would like to know.